# MS Luis.ai | Maximum number of utterances per intent/app

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, azure-language-understanding

Re my question on their GitHub page: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-LUIS-Windows/issues/17 my question is:

"Is there a maximum number of utterances that LUIS can handle per app/per intent?"

So, if we throw 2000 utterances at a single intent, and we have say 20 intents per luis-app, are we at risk of 'overloading/overfitting' luis? Will it's training time performance degrade considerably?

I know we could just go ahead and do that - throw thousands of utterances at each intent & back-up a copy of our luis-apps, but you know, if someone who helped make luis knows already, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, training will be ridiculously slow, especially if you have custom features (phrase features).
The idea of LUIS is to enable getting a reasonable model with few examples, so you might be overloading the app with insignificant gain.
If you want to enhance the prediction accuracy, you might need to check the quality of the utterances provided not just adding more.

Comment: Ok cool. So do you have a rough idea of what the maximum number of utterances actually is? Here's an example of what we were struggling with: help and hello are two very different intents but the words are very similar. LUIS was struggling to give us accurate answers when users enter things like 'hellp', 'helllo', 'helpp', 'heelo'. Etc. The only way we got LUIS to return accurate results was to throw about 30 or so variations on each at it

Comment: Actually I don't remember the exact number of intents allowed per App,  you might send and ask them. The problem you are describing is best solved by running a spell checking layer before sending the query to LUIS as LUIS has only the language lexicon and treats everything else (ex: typos) equally.

Comment: @MokhtarAshour: Implement Global Message handler for short utterances especially for Greetings(hi, hello etc) and exit (bye, thanks etc) https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-GlobalMessageHandlers